# How can I stop my Inbox from being flooded by spam edits?

Tags: support, notifications, spam

It's getting to the point where every time I login to the site, my notification indicator lights up with several "suggested edits" that are spamifications of my questions.  The edits are obviously being rejected instantly, so the system is working in that respect.  But if I don't keep clearing them out quickly, it will quickly make it impossible for me to see real notifications.

The edits seem to always be coming on the same two questions.  Would protecting the question prevent suggested edits from no rep users?

And this is probably more of an MSO question, but can we make it so that suggested edits that are rejected as spam don't notify the owner?

Comment: I too would like this feature.

Comment: I've found the repeated review notifications from this spammer annoying enough. I can't imagine how bad it must be for you on your own question.

Comment: I suggest you bring that to meta.SO and see if somebody's working on that feature, as they surely have a lot more edits suggested that Arcade. I bet you'll even find some duplicates of this question.

Comment: Is this happening on a specific answer or question that I can lock?

Comment: Yes, so far it is on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/47973 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/47972

Comment: I went looking on MSO and found some threads like - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190000/anonymous-user-suggested-edit-spam - where essentially people are saying "deal with it."  I'll see if I can raise this with our SE contacts and find out how endemic this is and if they're working on a solution.

Comment: Oh, you are being hit by this too. Uf. Noting this... To respond to one portion, protection has no effect on suggested edits.

Comment: Both those answers are not particularly high in votes... Would disassociating the user from the answer be acceptable to @bwarner, and reasonable as a remedy for a lack of any other?